# Convert varchar to float

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

In SSMS I have a source table and a destination table. In the source table, there is a column which usually contains decimal numbers, however, it will occasionally contain text when the user who is entering the values will enter 3,14 instead of 3.14 or "unknown", etc. (In the source table the user is technically allowed to enter in whatever they want. This rule cannot be changed.)

I have a stored procedure which picks some of the columns from the source table, including the column in question, and enters the information into a data warehouse so that we can analyze it.

My goal is to replace/convert the varchar values in the original column with either blank or -1, or some other placeholder for null.

I was told to create a custom function which would handle this, but I don't know how to do that and the documentation I've found online is way over my head at this point.

Here are the tables:

```
create table SourceTable (
    id INT,
    Column1 DATE,
    Column2 VARCHAR(50)
);
insert into SourceTable (id, Column1, Column2) values (1, '5/8/2017', '533');
insert into SourceTable (id, Column1, Column2) values (2, '10/1/2016', '988');
insert into SourceTable (id, Column1, Column2) values (3, '2/8/2016', '411');
insert into SourceTable (id, Column1, Column2) values (4, '2/29/2016', '491');
insert into SourceTable (id, Column1, Column2) values (5, '3/15/2016', '500');
insert into SourceTable (id, Column1, Column2) values (6, '4/2/2017', '677');
insert into SourceTable (id, Column1, Column2) values (7, '5/4/2016', '56/58');
insert into SourceTable (id, Column1, Column2) values (8, '8/24/2016', 'Unknown');
insert into SourceTable (id, Column1, Column2) values (9, '2/2/2017', '');
insert into SourceTable (id, Column1, Column2) values (10, '1/7/2017', '410');
```

---

```
create table Destination (
    id INT,
    Column1 DATE,
    Column2 float
);
```

How can I get the numbers from SourceTable.Column2 into Destination.Column2 (preferably using a custom function if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**

```
 Create FUNCTION dbo.FindNoneNumeric 
 (@FloatString VARCHAR(8000))
 RETURNS INT
 AS
 BEGIN
    Declare @Status int 
    SET @Status =
       (SELECT CASE 
     WHEN @FloatString NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
     THEN 1
     ELSE 0
     END)

     return @Status 
 END
```

**Insert Statement**

```
insert into Destination(ID,Column1,Column2)
Select ID,Column1,Column2 from  SourceTable
 where  dbo.FindNoneNumeric(SourceTable.Column2)=1
```

Comment: @john5 Please check .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try_cast(Column2 as float)` which will return `null` if it can not be cast to a `float` datatype.

If you want to replace `null` with a placeholder value as you suggested, you can use `isnull()` or `coalesce()`

```
insert into destination (id, column1, column2)
select id, column1, coalesce(try_cast(column2 as float),-1)
from sourcetable
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/FJTZ50419

returns:

```
+----+------------+---------+
| id |  column1   | column2 |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 | 2017-05-08 |     533 |
|  2 | 2016-10-01 |     988 |
|  3 | 2016-02-08 |     411 |
|  4 | 2016-02-29 |     491 |
|  5 | 2016-03-15 |     500 |
|  6 | 2017-04-02 |     677 |
|  7 | 2016-05-04 |      -1 |
|  8 | 2016-08-24 |      -1 |
|  9 | 2017-02-02 |       0 |
| 10 | 2017-01-07 |     410 |
+----+------------+---------+
```

In Sql Server 2012 and up: each of these will return `null` when the conversion fails instead of an error.

- [**`try_convert(datatype,val)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)
- [**`try_cast(val as datatype)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx)
- [**`try_parse(val as datatype [using culture])`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx)
- [Why doesn’t `isnumeric()` work correctly? (SQL Spackle)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use `ISNUMERIC` in this case where the users are putting in a variety of number types.

This will return 1 if the value is a number, or 0 if not. You should probably watch out for 1,303. If you know the user meant 1.303 then you can use the try cast, but if its actually one thousand... I don't know how you can guarantee your assumption.

[For more you can read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql)

Comment: Careful with `isnumeric()`. It might not do what you think it does. - [Why doesn’t `isnumeric()` work correctly? (SQL Spackle)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/)

Comment: Well that is painfully weird, needs an option to `isnumeric(var, notCrazyMode)

Answer (score 0):

You can use try_convert or case as below

```
Insert into Destination
select Id, Column1, Case when ISNUMERIC(Replace(column2,',','.')) = 1 then convert(float, Replace(column2,',','.')) else -1 end 
    from SourceTable
```

Comment: Careful with `isnumeric()`. It might not do what you think it does. - [Why doesn’t `isnumeric()` work correctly? (SQL Spackle)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/)